# Delphi: TFrame error No frames are available to insert

Tags: delphi, tframe

It happened to me, that the Delphi XE6 IDE *forgot* all of the `TFrame` descendants that I created in the past.

More specifically, when I click on Standard -> Frames, the dialog for choosing my frames does not show anymore.

Instead, it shows the following error message:

> No frames are available to insert. New frames may be created from the File|New|Other selections..

Is there a way to remedy the situation?

**EDIT1** Steps to reproduce are sadly unavailable: I am honestly unsure how this happened, but it did. I think there was maybe a culprit when upgrading from certain versions of Delphi to another. As I did this upgrade multiple times over time, I remember starting the project in Delphi 7, then there were some versions which I don't remember which ones, the last two versions I used were XE2 and until now is XE6.

---

**Edit2** This happens if the frame(s) was(were) created with a Delphi version before XE2.

Comment: I had this same issue with Delphi Rio 10.3, which at this time is the latest version of Delphi. Unfortunately, the fix suggested in the answer did not work to correct the problem.

Comment: Correction. The fix mentioned in the answer _did_ correct the problem. However, it was important that I added the <FormType> entry immediately below the <Form> entry. Note, also, I have no idea how the <FormType> element was removed from the .dproj file.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason for the problem is in changes to the `.dproj` file when the `Firemonkey` framework was added. To distinguish frames made for a `vcl` from frames made for `fmx` a line was added to the `.dproj` files as below. To make the correction to the `.dproj` file do as follows:

1. Close the Delphi IDE.
2. Open the `.dproj` file with a text editor of your choice.
3. Look up the `TFrame` one by one.
4. Let's suppose the following is your `TFrame` section:

   ```
   <DCCReference Include="Results.pas">
       <Form>FrameResults</Form>
       <DesignClass>TFrame</DesignClass>
   </DCCReference>
   ```
5. The fix is to add the following line into that section:

   ```
       <FormType>dfm</FormType>
   ```

(in `fmx` projects the line is `<FormType>fmx</FormType>`)

Comment: Your approach works most of the time, but sometimes you need to remove the unit of the frame from the project and reinsert again. I can see this issue also in Delphi 12.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue; the frame contents were not updating correctly and after updating and removing frames a few times it broke.  Under the project view I removed all the frames (Right Click remove from project) and added them again (Right Click on Project -> Add)

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen; in my case it was far simpler.

I had one fmx project that had some frames and a vcl project that didn't in a single project group (different sub directories).

If I opened a fmx unit and tried to add a frame from the component menu, but had the vcl project as the compile target then I got this message.  Changing the compile target to the application that contains the unit I opened and the collection of frames stopped the error.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the IDE. Specifically, IDE offers `IOTASourceEditor` interface, which has `CreateWriter` method to obtain a `IOTAEditWriter` interface.

Some IDE extension may use methods of `IOTAEditWriter` interface to (for example) edit content of .dpr file (basically, just a series of `.DeleteTo` and `.Insert` is enough). Apparently this is somehow forces IDE to corrupt .dproj file.